# datetick too many output arguments

Tags: matlab

I have a time-series containing 900 entries, stored in a 900x2 matrix (first column are datenumbers converted from excel e.g. 732994 to represent 13-nov-2006, second column is the reading at each day) I would like to plot them out with the years marked out on the x-axis, using the `datestr` function.

here is my code segment.

```
x=newsgdata(:,1);
x=num2str(x); %converts datenumbers from int to string
dateline=datetick('x','yyyy');
plot(dateline,newsgdata(:,2))
```

when i run this code, i get the error: **Error using datetick Too many output arguments.**

I have tried running `plot(datetick('x','yyyy'),newsgdata(:,2))` but the same error keeps popping up.

Comment: Just remove `dateline=` from the third line of your code.

Comment: thank you, that helps it to work. However, how do I plot the graph out? plot(newsgdata(:,2)) does not display the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, plot vs the datenum directly:

```
plot(newsgdata(:,1), newsgdata(:,2));
```

Then, use `datetick` to convert the labels from datenums to strings.

```
datetick('x', 'yyyy')
```